# Multi-Tenant Application Owin External Logins

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, owin, wif

I'm building a Multi-Tenant application and I'm having problems for specify multiple sub-domains for a Facebook and Google external login witn Owin and WIF.

The tenants are using a sub-domain for example:

```
http://tenant-1.domain.com/
http://tenant-2.domain.com/
http://tenant-3.domain.com/
```

With Facebook and Google I can't specify multiple sub-domains for returns url of an application.

What are other solutions to this problem?

I thought about building a single login page, and after making the login to identify users, and perform the routing to tenant corresponding subdomain. The problem is that each tenant access his own database, and this solution involves having a common database of all users.

In short, I need to use external logins with a multi-tenant with a subdomain for each tenant. I do not think this problem is so rare, and the answers in stackoverflow are old, and no longer apply because have changed the application settings in Facebook and Google.

Comment: As far as Facebook goes, you can only specify one domain for Facebook login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we adopt a solution-type like Single Sign On Server, which separates all user management from applications.

We recommend for such solutions, Identity Server v3 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).

Thanks!